# NavigateURl leads to HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request

Tags: asp.net

Ok I have a gallery with thumbnail images that is sorrounded with a tags like this

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl= '<% String.Format("?name = {0}", Container.DataItem) %>'
runat="server">
<asp:Image CssClass="images" ImageUrl= '<%# String.Format("~/pictures/thumbs/{0}",
Container.DataItem) %>' runat="server">
</asp:Image>
</asp:HyperLink>   
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

But when I click an image I just get the HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request error.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: can you show us the rendered html ?

Answer (score 1):

You have not pass navigation url

```
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl= '<% String.Format("YourPageName.aspx?name = {0}", Container.DataItem) %>'
runat="server">
```

Comment: check the navigation url in firebug